# how to make cube with only Right & Top side using OpenGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d, core-graphics

I want to show simple `Cube with Right & Top` portion , Below is the image which is i am looing for.

[image]

i had refer  [this link](http://www.endodigital.com/opengl-es-2-0-on-the-iphone/part-fourteen-creating-the-cube/) and try to edit as per my required but don't getting success.

Comment: Do you just want to draw a incomplete cube with 2 faces? You may want to post the exact code that you have tried..

Comment: @kentoh yes . i dont want 3D cube with Rotation . Please guide me how to make this ..